# When was MS Message Queue first released?

Tags: msmq, history

When was MS Message Queue first released?

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing

Since Windows NT 4.0 and Windows 95, so 1995-ish.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. .NET 4.0 wasn't released until 1996 and I'm pretty sure MSMQ was first introduced in an NT 4 service pack.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NT 4 Option Pack 3 was the first release of MSMQ. That puts the technology in May of 1997.